# Scheduling with Google messages. What does the roll-out information mean?

Tags: google-messages

This [news article](https://www.androidpolice.com/2021/02/23/scheduled-sending-is-going-live-in-google-messages-for-some/) describes the roll-out of Google's new scheduling feature for Google Messages. On my own phone, I briefly had the opportunity to use the feature before it inexplicably disappeared. The news article seems to suggest two things: first, that the brief opportunity to use the feature might have been part of a test prior to the general roll-out, and second, that "schedule send is rolling out as a server-side switch ..."

What exactly does that last part, about server-side switch actually mean. I understand the general principle of client-server relationships with things like using an email client on my PC connected to my ISP's email server, but what server is being talked about in connection with Google messages. Surely they're not talking about something that requires cooperation from every ISP!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that feature will be enable by Google's server. You might already have the feature but you won't see it on the app's interface.

> Surely they're not talking about something that requires cooperation from every ISP!?

It is not related to ISPs. Often due to the high number of users, some features are not "open" for all of them, but enable to users from the server (in this case Google's) slowly based on country, language, phone model, etc until all can use it.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand. Are you saying that scheduling with Google Messages only works if one has one's device signed into a Google account and shares one's message with Google?

Comment: @user02814 it means that the availability of the feature is controlled by Google's side, and that the app/device needs to contact Google server to retrieve this info. A bit similar to [staged rollouts on Play Store](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6346149).

Comment: @AndrewT. Thank you. That would explain the disappearance of the feature. My device is not normally signed into Google, so I probably saw the feature on a rare occasion when there was Google account info on the device. I might add, that it seems to me to be a disgraceful privacy-invading way of implementing the thing.